# Optimize ORDER BY using a column from left join MySql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a complicated query that use left join and conditions, I will try to make it simple to avoid the complication.

I have two tables `posts` and `metadata` and both tables has indexes, my query like:

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM posts
LEFT JOIN `metadata` ON `metadata`.`extended_type`='App\Post' AND `metadata`.`extended_id` = `posts`.`id` AND `metadata`.`key`='display_date'
WHERE metadata.value <= DATE(NOW()) AND posts.type='type' AND posts.published=1
ORDER BY metadata.value DESC limit 8;
```

the field value is `date` type and already indexed.

The query take `0.84 sec`.
When I remove the `ORDER BY` or use `posts.created_at` column to order, the query take `0.00 sec`.

Is there any way to use `FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY` from the joined table?
or is there any way to make the query faster?

## Update #1

Show create for table posts

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `posts_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `posts_type_index` (`type`),
  KEY `posts_published_index` (`published`),
  KEY `posts_sort_index` (`sort`),
  KEY `posts_deleted_at_index` (`deleted_at`),
  KEY `posts_created_at_index` (`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `posts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39302 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Show create for post_contents

```
CREATE TABLE `post_contents` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lang` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ar',
  `title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `post_contents_post_id_foreign` (`post_id`),
  KEY `post_contents_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `post_contents_lang_index` (`lang`),
  KEY `post_contents_published_index` (`published`),
  KEY `post_contents_post_id_lang_index` (`lang`(2)),
  CONSTRAINT `post_contents_post_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `post_contents_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84100 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Show create for meta_data table

```
CREATE TABLE `meta_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `extended_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `extended_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_int` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_float` decimal(20,9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_string` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `meta_data_unique_key` (`extended_id`,`extended_type`,`key`),
  KEY `meta_data_extended_type_index` (`extended_type`),
  KEY `meta_data_key_index` (`key`),
  KEY `meta_data_value_int_index` (`value_int`),
  KEY `meta_data_value_date_index` (`value_date`),
  KEY `meta_data_value_float_index` (`value_float`),
  KEY `meta_data_value_string_index` (`value_string`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=330592 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The real query is:

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts`
  LEFT JOIN `post_contents` ON `post_contents`.`post_id`=`posts`.`id` AND `post_contents`.`lang`='en'
  LEFT JOIN `meta_data` ON `meta_data`.`extended_id`=`post_contents`.`id` AND `meta_data`.`extended_type` = 'App\\PostContent' AND `meta_data`.`key`='display_date'
WHERE
  `posts`.`type` = 'type' AND
  `posts`.`published` = 1 AND
  exists(
      SELECT *
      FROM `post_contents`
      WHERE
        `posts`.`id` = `post_contents`.`post_id` AND
        `lang` = 'en' AND
        `published` = 1
        AND
        exists(
            SELECT *
            FROM `meta_data`
            WHERE
              `post_contents`.`id` = `meta_data`.`extended_id` AND
              `meta_data`.`extended_type` = 'App\\PostContent' AND
              `key` = 'display_date' AND
              `value_date` <= DATE(now()))
  ) AND
  NOT exists(
      SELECT *
      FROM `meta_data`
      WHERE
        `posts`.`id` = `meta_data`.`extended_id` AND
        `meta_data`.`extended_type` = 'App\\Post' AND
        `key` = 'not_in_home' AND
        `value_int` = 1
  ) AND
  `posts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY `meta_data`.`value_date` DESC
LIMIT 8;
```

Query explain result:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: posts
         type: ref
possible_keys: posts_type_index,posts_published_index,posts_deleted_at_index
          key: posts_type_index
      key_len: 766
          ref: const
         rows: 22112
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: post_contents
         type: ref
possible_keys: post_contents_post_id_foreign,post_contents_lang_index,post_contents_post_id_lang_index
          key: post_contents_post_id_foreign
      key_len: 4
          ref: tislamqa_db.posts.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: meta_data
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: meta_data_unique_key,meta_data_extended_type_index,meta_data_key_index
          key: meta_data_unique_key
      key_len: 1536
          ref: tislamqa_db.post_contents.id,const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 4
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: meta_data
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: meta_data_unique_key,meta_data_extended_type_index,meta_data_key_index,meta_data_value_int_index
          key: meta_data_unique_key
      key_len: 1536
          ref: tislamqa_db.posts.id,const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: post_contents
         type: ref
possible_keys: post_contents_post_id_foreign,post_contents_lang_index,post_contents_published_index,post_contents_post_id_lang_index
          key: post_contents_post_id_foreign
      key_len: 4
          ref: tislamqa_db.posts.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: meta_data
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: meta_data_unique_key,meta_data_extended_type_index,meta_data_key_index,meta_data_value_date_index
          key: meta_data_unique_key
      key_len: 1536
          ref: tislamqa_db.post_contents.id,const,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the `ORDER BY` not using the indexes when I use the `exists` condition with subquery, I changed my query to use `JOIN` statements with `where` conditions.

My last query:

```
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts`
  JOIN `post_contents` ON `post_contents`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` AND `post_contents`.`lang` = 'en' AND `post_contents`.`published` = 1
  JOIN `meta_data` as m ON m.`extended_id` = `post_contents`.`id` AND m.`extended_type` = 'App\\PostContent' AND m.`key` = 'display_date'
  LEFT JOIN `meta_data` as n ON n.`extended_id` = `posts`.`id` AND n.`extended_type` = 'App\\POST' AND n.`key` = 'not_in_home'
WHERE
  `posts`.`type` = 'fatawa' AND
  `posts`.`published` = 1 AND
   m.`value_date` <= DATE(now()) AND
   n.`value_int` != 1 AND
  `posts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY m.`value_date` DESC
LIMIT 8;
```

It took `0.00 sec`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` but don't actually select any columns from joined table. It means that in a case if there is no linked `metadata` is available for `posts` row - this `posts` row will still be included into results set. It makes almost whole filtering from your query to be meaningless.

You have no separate index on `extended_id` row into `metadata` table that you're using for join. Of course it is part of `meta_data_unique_key` index, but I would look at `EXPLAIN` clause for your query to see if use of this index actually takes place. It may also be good idea to create explicit foreign key from `metadata` to `posts` since you're using InnoDB engine.

Since `ORDER BY` works on resulted set rather then on source tables but you don't have sorted column into your resulted set - it (most likely) forces MySQL to operate with whole contents of `metadata` table and, taking in mind auto-increment value in it - it is pretty large data set.

I would propose to try to use `INNER JOIN` and include `metadata.value` field into your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I update the question and add the real query with the explain result @Flying

Comment: I tried also to use `INNER JOIN` and added the `value_date` column to selected fields, I got the same result :(

Comment: @Aboudeh87 your `explain` for first query have `Using temporary; Using filesort` and works with 22112 rows. It means that MySQL saves all result into temp.file and sorts a file. Of course it is slow. As can be seen from [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html#order-by-optimizer-control) there is a number of optimization techniques, but you may want to increase in-memory sort buffer size. Of course it will come at a price of more memory use, but should help avoiding file sorting operations. Use of memory-mapped disk may also help.

Comment: for some reason the `order by` not using the indexes when i use `exists` condition, i changed my query and every things now is good, i will write an answer with the new query to be reference if some one faced the same issue

Comment: It looks like a LEFT JOIN. It's actually an INNER JOIN.